# Three dropdown event change not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I am trying to populate second dropdown on change of first dropdown and populate third dropdown on change of second dropdown.

Here is my code:

```
$("#categories").change(function() {
    var cat = $('#categories').val();
    alert();

    $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "get_partner.php",
            data: {
                'categlist': cat
            }
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            $("#patner").remove();
            $("#cbselect").prepend(data);

        });

});
$('#patner').change(function() {
    alert();
});
```

When first dropdown is changed, alert works fine, but not happening any alert for second dropdown change.

Here is the HTML for Dropdowns:

```
<div id='cbselect'><select class="input-large m-wrap" tabindex="1" id="categories" name="categlist" >
   <option value="0"> Select Category</option>
</select></div>
<select class="input-large m-wrap" tabindex="1" id="patner" name="patner" >
   <option value="0"> Select Partner</option>
</select>
<select class="input-large m-wrap cbs" tabindex="1" id="outlet" name="outlet" >
   <option value="0"> Select Outlet</option>
</select>
```

Comment: But your code suggests something else, on change of first select you are removing second select

Comment: because your re binding event to the non-existing element. when you send 1st ajax call - in success block you're removing $(#patner), then you are adding again a new element also called $(#patner), but it's not the same, that Jquery rememebers from the first load. do a delegation style binding for second and third selects - $(document).change("#patner",function(){ ... ur stuff ... })

Comment: i should not remove old one.. and add options what you are suggesting. right ?

Comment: yes, that could be better, leave complete #patner select alone and just remove its options and populate them

Comment: i have tried to add script with ajax response but it is not showing any jquery at runtime.

Comment: @GL.awog.. Thanks... i am trying something you suggested... how can i use array for populating option ?

Comment: theres no need adding script again, it's already on the page, change selects manipulation as you suggested urself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work,
Use ajax in this way.

```
$.post(
  'get_partner.php',
  {'categlist': cat},
  function(ret_data){
    $('#patner').html(ret_data); /* Take even the select Partner option from the ajax page */
  }
);
```

Comment: Trying your answer as well.